# MYSQL - datetime to seconds

Tags: mysql, datetime

I wasn't able to find out (googling, reading mysql reference manual) how to get value of **DATETIME in seconds** in MySQL.

I dont mean to extract seconds from datetime, but to convert it into seconds.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

If you want to have the difference between two DATETIME values, use [**`TIMESTAMPDIFF`**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff):

> **TIMESTAMPDIFF(unit,datetime_expr1,datetime_expr2)**
>
> Returns `datetime_expr2 – datetime_expr1`, where `datetime_expr1` and `datetime_expr2` are date or datetime expressions. One expression may be a date and the other a datetime; a date value is treated as a datetime having the time part '00:00:00' where necessary. The unit for the result (an integer) is given by the unit argument. The legal values for unit are the same as those listed in the description of the `TIMESTAMPADD()` function.

```
mysql> SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH,'2003-02-01','2003-05-01');  
    -> 3  



mysql> SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR,'2002-05-01','2001-01-01');  
    -> -1  


mysql> SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,'2003-02-01','2003-05-01 12:05:55');  
    -> 128885
```

`unit` can also be `HOUR` which is what you asked for in one of the comments.

The unit argument can be any of the following:

- MICROSECOND
- SECOND
- MINUTE
- HOUR
- DAY
- WEEK
- MONTH
- QUARTER
- YEAR

The level of usefulness of some of the other options will of course be determined by the granularity of the data. For instance, "MICROSECOND" will only have limited use if you are not storing microseconds in your DATETIME values.

Comment: Sorry, but I am asking about whole DATETIME :(

Answer (score 50):

If by "*convert to seconds*", you mean "*convert to an [UNIX Timestamp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time)*" *(i.e. number of seconds since `1970-01-01`)*, then you can use the [`UNIX_TIMESTAMP`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp) function :

```
select UNIX_TIMESTAMP(your_datetime_field)
from your_table
where ...
```

And, for the sake of completness, to convert from an Unix Timestamp to a datetime, you can use the [`FROM_UNIXTIME`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime) function.

Comment: good
and when I want DIFFERENCE between two datetimes in HOURS, should I use something like? : 

select (unix_timestamp('2010-01-02 18:00:00') - unix_timestamp('2010-01-01 16:00:00'))/60/60;

Comment: I suppose the TIMESTAMPDIFF function should do the trick : it allows one to specify the desired unit (see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff )

Comment: thank you, Felix already suggested using timesteampdiff, thats what I wanted

Comment: You're welcome :-) *(Well, it was hard to guess from your question that you wanted to find out the difference between two datetimes ^^ )*

Comment: Yep I thought I'll make it like (datetime_to_sec(value1) - datetime_to_sec(value2))*60*24 - but thats rubbish as I see now :))

Answer (score 7):

Use TIME_TO_SEC in previous versions for mysql

SELECT TIME_TO_SEC(time column) FROM table

Answer (score 4):

i used in mysql

TO_SECONDS(your date goes here) method to convert date to seconds from year 0

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Answer (score 3):

The function UNIX_TIMESTAMP(*datetime*) returns the unix time, which happens to be the number of seconds since 1-Jan-1970 0000 UTC.  That may be what you need, but not if you're dealing with dates of birth, historical dates, or dates after 2037.

Answer (score 2):

Starting in mysql 5.5.0 you can use `to_seconds()`

```
TO_SECONDS(FIELD_NAME)
```

FIELD_NAME must be `DATETIME` type

Answer (score 0):

I have created my own query for your problem:

```
SELECT HOUR(`colname`) * 3600 + MINUTE(`colname`) * 60 + SECOND(`colname`)
FROM widgets
WHERE id = 1;
```

- Use `id = 1` if you have to take a specific row.
- The output will be in seconds.

Comment: The question has already been answered a long time ago, and the accepted answer also deals with days, not just hours and minutes. The OP clarified in a comment that he wanted to calculate the difference between two datetimes in hours.