# Getting the difference between two MYSQL datetime columns in seconds

Tags: php, mysql, database, datetime

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [MYSQL - datetime to seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2438828/mysql-datetime-to-seconds)

If I have a datetime column in a mysql table, how can I get the difference between NOW() and that column in seconds?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

by `TIMEDIFF` you can get the differense by seconds

```
    SELECT TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF('2007-01-09 10:24:46','2007-01-09 10:23:46'));
```

or this

```
SELECT DATEDIFF('2007-12-31 10:02:00','2007-12-30 12:01:01') * 24*60*60;
// result: 86400 the difference in seconds for days.
```

or:

```
 SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,'2007-12-30 12:01:01','2007-12-31 10:02:00'); 
 // result: 79259  the difference in seconds with the time.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:  SELECT NOW() - my_col AS my_diff