# Getting a MySQL DateTime in PHP to seconds in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, datetime

I have a countdown timer in javascript. It has two variables. Both store current dates. One variable (`currentDate`) is converted to milliseconds and then milliseconds according to 10 minutes is added. Other variable (`d`) stores current datetime in a function that is run every second. That function takes difference between these two and displays in seconds. That works. Below is the code.

```
<script>
    var currentDate = new Date();
    var d =new Date();

    var tl =  currentDate.setTime(currentDate.getTime() + 2*60*1000);
    var seconds =(tl - d)/1000;
    function secondPassed() {

      var minutes = Math.round((seconds - 30)/60);
      var remainingSeconds = seconds % 60;
      if (remainingSeconds < 10) {
          remainingSeconds = "0" + remainingSeconds;  
      }
      document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = minutes + ":" + remainingSeconds;
      if (seconds == 0) {
        clearInterval(countdownTimer);
        document.getElementById('bonus').innerHTML = "Buzz Buzz";
      } else {
        seconds--;
      }
  }

  var countdownTimer = setInterval('secondPassed()', 1000);
</script>
```

But problem is that every time I refresh the page, the countdown starts again from 10 minutes. I want to store a particular datetime (TIMESTAMP) in php (which will be stored when user visits the page). Then I will add 10 minutes to that and that datetime will be taken as reference in javascript to subtract current timestamp from.

So basically I need to convert php datetime (TIME_STAMP) to milliseconds, give that to javascript, add milliseconds according to 10 minutes to it, and subtract milliseconds corresponding to current datetime to get remaining time in the function.

The gettime method in javascript uses 1970-01-01 00:00:00 as refernce to convert into milliseconds. So, in short I need to get milliseconds between that and the stored datetime(TIMESTAMP). How can I do it?

I need to do this in php, not MySQL, so this question : [MYSQL - datetime to seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2438828/mysql-datetime-to-seconds) does not help me.

EDIT : I am storing date as TIMESTAMP in MySQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use PHP's `time` function to get seconds since the epoch:

> Returns the current time measured in the number of seconds since the Unix Epoch (January 1 1970 00:00:00 GMT).

https://www.php.net/time

It's not *completely* clear to me from your question how you're storing the time stamp in the DB, but if it's a MySQL `DATETIME`, when you select it from the DB use `SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(time_col)` to convert it to seconds since the epoch on the fly.  Now you're dealing with UNIX timestamps in all cases.

[UNIX_TIMESTAMP docs here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp)

Comment: After SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(time_col), how do I store it in php variable?

Comment: Look at the PHP docs for the `PDO` or `myslqi` functions for how to read from a database in PHP.