# MySQL substract two datetimes and returns in nanoseconds

Tags: mysql, date, datetime

I have 2 `datetime` columns in a MySQL table.

I want to subtract it and return the results and a nanoseconds precision

This is my code so far.

```
select end,start,end-start from job where id=1;
```

I have the results like this

```
'2014-04-02 12:30:00', '2014-04-02 10:30:00', 20000.000000
```

Just for curiosity how MySQL subtract directly, how `20000.000000` came from.

I am not good handling dates. Which is the best approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[**unix_timestamp**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestampfunctions.html): If you want to convert a UNIX TIMESTAMP into seconds since '1970-01-01'

---

> If called with no argument, returns a Unix timestamp (seconds since
>   '1970-01-01 00:00:00' UTC) as an unsigned integer. If UNIX_TIMESTAMP()
>   is called with a date argument, it returns the value of the argument
>   as **seconds** since '1970-01-01 00:00:00' UTC. date may be a DATE string,
>   a DATETIME string, a TIMESTAMP, or a number in the format YYMMDD or
>   YYYYMMDD.

Consider this :

```
SELECT unix_timestamp(now()) - unix_timestamp('2007-03-19 09:50:00')
```

You want this:

```
SELECT unix_timestamp(column1) - unix_timestamp(column2) from tableName
```

[See it in action](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4fb11/1)

```
SELECT start_time, 
       end_time, 
       ( Unix_timestamp(start_time) - Unix_timestamp(end_time) ) * 1000000000 AS 
       NanoSeconds 
FROM   job
```

Output:

```
start_time      |       end_time           |    NanoSeconds
April, 02 2014 12:30:00 April, 02 2014 10:30:00 7200000000000
```

As we can format this datetime column value also with `DATE_FORMAT()`. [**TO_SECONDS()**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_to-seconds) is available beginning with MySQL 5.5.0.

[MYSQL - datetime to seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2438828/mysql-datetime-to-seconds) also gives some lightness on another solution of the *output* you want.